# How to set a vector of pointers = to nullptr in c++?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, inheritance, smart-pointers

I have the following code

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Account>> openedAccounts;
```

(Account is a class), so I have a vector of pointers and I know the best practice when making pointers is to initialize it with something or make sure its assigned to nullptr, however when i do `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Account>> openedAccounts = nullptr;` or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Account>> openedAccounts = std::vector<nullptr>;` it doesn't work, so how would I set the `openedAccounts` to a `nullptr`?

Comment: Note that the recommendation of initialising a pointer to nullptr _only_ applies to raw pointers. All well defined smart pointers (of which `unique_ptr` is one) will default themselves to their equivalent of `nullptr` on construction so you never need to worry about it. This is true for a standalone `unique_ptr` or one in a `std::vector`. Separately a `std::vector` is guaranteed empty on creation (unless you specifically use one of the non-default constructors that will fill it but you have to deliberately do that).

Comment: A vector is not a nullable type. The closest thing would be an empty vector, which is what a default constructed vector is.

Comment: A **vector** of pointers is a *vector*, not a *pointer*.

Answer (score 3):

A default-constructed `std::vector` is empty, so you're all clear.

Similarly, a default-constructed `std::unique_ptr` is null, so resizing your vector will work out-of-the-box as well.

Comment: thanks so the way i have it currently is fine / compiles with best practices? thank you

Answer (score 1):

A vector isn't a pointer, nor is it a class that emulates a pointer i.e. it is not a smart pointer nor a fancy pointer. You cannot assign `nullptr` to a vector nor can you assign `nullptr` to it. There is no such thing as a null vector.

If you want to initialise the vector to be empty, you can use default initialisation as you did in your example (value initialisation also works). No further steps are necessary.

Comment: thanks so the way i have it currently is fine / compiles with best practices? thank you

Comment: @mathewsjoyy Best practice would probably be to use `std::vector<Account>` unless you have a special reason to do otherwise.

Comment: @eeroika so i will use this in a banking application and let users open different accounts, so i need a vector of pointers, rather than just a normal vector of accounts in order to be able to allocate memory on demand, as I dont know how many accounts a user would end up making. Would this be good use case?

Comment: @mathewsjoyy If by "different accounts", you mean different types of accounts, then yes. Object oriented polymorphism is reasonable use case.

Comment: yes Account is base i have current and savings which inherits, thank you